Present continuous and conditionals
I could say:

" If she comes I will cook something special"

I can imagine that if I want to emphasize that it is my plan to cook something nice I could use present continuous instead of future simple and say

"If she comes I'm cooking something special"

Yet, 2 may be ambiguous it can also mean that I already started cooking before she came.
My big concern is what if I report my 2 example in indirect speech. Then, it becomes

"If she came I was cooking something special"

So, in the past it has only one meaning that I started cooking before her arrival but it's weired that only by reporting one meaning is excluded or I'm mistaken somewhere?

#3 works differently but it's not reported speech. You're saying if it was true that she visited Monday, then yes I must have been cooking for her. All 3 need a comma before the "I" part.

It would be better to use "I am/was going to cook" to talk about a plan.  I would personally avoid No.2 and No.3.  To me, these would imply a spur of the moment decision, not a plan.

This feels very familiar. Searching the site for text from this question, I don't see a duplicate, but I feel like I remember it from a few weeks or months ago?

Heh, maybe I'm thinking of the similar question from earlier today. Anyway, the whole #3 section isn't clear enough to answer yet. It isn't indirect speech, it's just a sentence in quotation marks, and "If/then" doesn't work in such simple ways in the past. That's just because the future is unknown, so we can use conditionals about it a lot, but the past is set in stone. We could use conditionals when describing a point in the past in which we were unsure what was about to happen... but that's so complicated it deserves its own question.

Meanwhile, "2 may be ambiguous it can also mean that I already started cooking before she came": No, it can't have that meaning; it's just like simple future. You might be thinking of "If she comes I'll be cooking," but that still doesn't have the ambiguous meaning that "When she comes" does, since the "if/then" conditional makes the cooking a consequence of the coming.

@AndyBonner what do you mean by saying 3 isn't reported speech? If we use ise reported speech and things said by someone are no longer true then we backshift tenses the way I did. So why not?

I can imagine examples which backshifted don't make any sense such as " When I get there, I'm kissing her" once backshifted it is "When I got there, I was kissing her". As I can see the past version doesn't make sense.  Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

Only direct speech is put between inverted commas (quotation marks). Reported speech would be I told him that if she came I was cooking something special.

@KateBunting How about my example with "kissing" amd how it changes in reported speech? Could you comment on that too?

I mean that it's not reported speech because no one is "reporting" it. "I told John 'You can't do that'"—that's direct reported speech. "I told John he couldn't do that"—that's indirect reported speech. "You can't do that"—that's just dialogue or quotation. I'd like to hear more in other questions about the notion that the choice of tense depends on the statement still being true; I think it might be the misunderstanding that drove your earlier question. I can think of many examples in which we could use past tense even if the statement is still true.

Meanwhile, did you see this question? Note some of the advice there. Using future continuous as a 1-to-1 substitute for future simple is possible but not mandatory and not even necessarily a idea, especially for learners.

Your 'kissing' example sounds rather odd in direct speech. Yes, I know we can use the present tense to refer to future plans (I'm going to London next week), but you would be much more likely to hear When I get there, I'm going to kiss her. As for reported speech, I told her that when I got there I was kissing her sounds even odder.

@KateBunting I know that it isn't very likely but I'm sure some natives would use presen continuous in my example with kissing. Yet, once backshifted my example with present continuous simple doesn't make much sense. So, what are your thoughts? Is it then a grammatical mistake to use continuous in my example with kissing. Just, say something more if you could. Thanks

Ngrams finds no results for When I get there I'm , and the few for When I arrive I'm are either from narratives in the present tense or I'm is the start of a new sentence. I would say your example is very unidiomatic rather than grammatically wrong. Why are you so determined to find justification for bizarre combinations of tenses?

@KateBunting it is just strange to me that I could say something like " when you come I'm going to kiss you" meaning after their arrival and once reported "when you came I was going to kiss you" it still has the same meaning after their arrival. But my version with present continuous which is unidiomatic "When you come I'm kissing you" yet grammaticaly correct "I do it after her arrival" once backshifted is wrong "when you came I was kissing you". How can you start kissing them before they even arrive. Yet , present continuois is used for planned events but in this type of sentences it doesn't

Work and I don't know why

"How can you start kissing them before they even arrive ?" That is precisely why When I get there I'm kissing her is so unidiomatic! As far as I  can see it doesn't break any rules, since we can use the present continuous for future plans, but it just sounds strange.
